# Android: Most efficient way to periodically (in the background) open tcp connection for ~2 minutes

Tags: java, android, tcp, background

I'm working on Android application that sends periodically (every 5-10 minutes, user dependent) requests to some server. The server performs heavy calculation and sends response/data back after ~2 minutes.

I want to know what is the most efficient way - mainly in battery life, to do this.

I'm in the middle of writing the application, and right now, I plan to run the application as a service that periodically opens tcp connection to the server, and then waits for response (just keep the tcp connection open), and then closes the connection.

I believe that there are better ways to do this (1. run job periodically in the background. 2. manage tcp connections where there is a client-request and response from the server only after 2 minutes.). I searched in the internet for such things, but couldn't find such a case (mainly about the tcp connection management problem). 
Again, my main interest is in battery life.

I have to mention that in my case, there is no option to use solutions like GCM (the client sends request, the server sends notification, the client pulls the response). Therefore, I believe that I must use tcp (or udp) connection, and I just want to know how to do this most efficiently.

Any advice?

By the way, what is the cost of such application in battery life?

Comment: Push notification really is the right way to do this. You should try to make it an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read the android article "Optimizing Downloads for Efficient Network Access" (https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html)

Sending data every 5-10 minutes will drain the battery, and waiting 2 minutes for an answer will worsen the problem (especially at a frequency of 5 minutes it will mean that basically the device's radio will be in use all the time).

Consider moving the (intensive) calculation to the device. I think it is justified in this case. Or consider sending the data not as often.

In any case, don't keep the connection open for 2 minutes. If you really want to stick to your current solution let the server return a token immediately, and use that token to re-query the server after ~2 minutes.

Apart from battery drain by keeping the radio alive your service will prevent the device from going to sleep, adding further battery drain. Maybe you need that to collect the data you want to send to your server, but otherwise consider using an alarm to have your service send the data on the device's default wake up times.

Comment: The problem is that I don't control the server. Right now I must play by the server's rules (the token option is impossible).

Comment: If the token option would be the way to go consider injecting a simple middle-man server yourself. That server will be able to return a token, and will have no problems waiting for several minutes. By the way, don't sockets tend to time out if they have to wait so long?